# Is it Possible to make video conference app for iPad 2 and iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, video, conference, ipad-2

I was asked to make an app for ipad2/iphone4 to make video conference, I have googled a while but did not find much could help.

Can anyone do me a favor?  any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

But it is not a trivial (aka 'easy') development project.  To get started you'll need to become fairly expert in:

- iPhone/iPad development.  Meaning [Object-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) on [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29)
- [video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec), containers and realtime [streaming protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media)

This is a very opened ended question.  You probably should start out by experimenting with existing iOS video Apps ([FaceTime](http://www.apple.com/mac/facetime/)) and maybe desktop video conferencing solutions.  Then design something and start asking more specific questions on StackOverflow.

Good luck.

Comment: hateres gonna hate (and are to lazy to comment why)